# Retrieve Dailymotion Games chat messages

Tags: chat, live-streaming, dailymotion-api

I would like to retrieve Dailymotion Games chat messages using their API, but the official documentation is not very clear on this point => https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/203886473-Dailymotion-live-API-for-developers

I tried to use the API to retrieve comments of a video with my live video id (endpoint => https://api.dailymotion.com/video/[LIVE_VIDEO_ID]/comments), but it doesn't return any chat messages...

Do you know if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've searched a little bit more and I found a more elegant way to do that avoiding the scraping method.

In fact the embed chat page (returned by the **chat_embed_url**) use [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventSource) to get notified when a new message arrived.

With [this](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/eventsource) good NPM package, I've been able to retrieve chat messages in only 5 lines:

```
var EventSource = require('eventsource');

var url = 'http://dmchat.dailymotion.com/rooms/[USERNAME]-[CHANNEL_ID]';
var es = new EventSource(url);
es.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    console.log(e.data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A comment on a video is different from the chat feature, this is why chat messages don't appear in comments.

You can't get individual chat messages so far, but you can get the chat embed code on two different ways:

- using the Dailymotion API, you can request the [chat_embed_html](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-chat_embed_html-field) or [chat_embed_url](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-chat_embed_url-field) fields on the video object
- or you can get it directly from the video pages on dailymotion games, by clicking on the settings icon below the chat, and click "copy embed code"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Do you know if it's planned for the future?

For now, I will perform scraping on the URL retrieve from **chat_embed_url**.